# Keycloak: Differnentiate Login Error for Disabled Account

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, keycloak

When a disabled user tries to login, he gets an error `400 Bad Request` (`error: "invalid_grant"`, `error_description: "Account disabled"`). However, in my project, there are multiple reasons for a user to be disabled, which are distinguishable by certain attributes I set to the user.

My goal is to create a Keycloak extension to customize the response based on those attributes, so that a different error message can be shown to the user. Providing a different value `error_description` would be a solution.

My question is: Is it possible to intercept that error message before it is sent to the client, and if so, what kind of SPI do I need to write to handle that?

I am using Keycloak version 3.4.3 Final.

Comment: A similar issue (however dealing with lockouts, not with disabled users) is discussed here: http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-dev/2016-September/008162.html
It seems like the error message should rather not be differentiated, because a possible attacker could profit from additional information.